# jQuery prop method not working outside $(document).ready( )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to change the text of an button made with the Input tag

When this statement

```
$clearbutton.prop('value', "New Text For The Button");
```

is inside the

```
$(document).ready( function{  } );
```

It does its job well.

But if I put the same statement outside the ready( ) in a function defined outside ready( )

it does not execute

```
sendtext5 = "Bwahahaha";
sendtext4 = "Send Text 4";

$eraser.prop('value', sendtext5);       // NOT WORKING
$clearbutton.prop('value', sendtext5);  // NOT WORKING
$screen2top.text(sendtext4); // Works
$oneword.text(sendtext4);    // Works
alert("BEFORE CLEARBUTTON"); // Works
```

The HTML5 is

```
<input type="button" data-role="button" id="clearbutton" class="eraser" value="Remo">
```

I also tried the following

```
$(".eraser").prop('value', sendtext5);  
$("#clearbuton").prop('value', sendtext5);
```

But either one of the above two statements work correctly when those statements are placed inside $document.ready( ) ;

I also realized that sendtext5 variables do display the correct value.  I used alert(sendtext5); to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a web page, there are usually situations where the javascript is being executed while the HTML is still loading. If the browser is executing a jQuery selector for a HTML element before that element has loaded, there is nothing for the jQuery to find.
e.g. `<div id="wrapper">...</div>` can be referenced with `$("#wrapper")`, but if the reference runs before the `<div>` has loaded, there is nothing to find.

The jQuery solution to this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //things to do when document has fully loaded
})
```

In your case, some selectors work by the sheer luck that the elements they reference happen to have been loaded at the time this line runs.

Comment: Well now, and it does not work inside ready( ) either.  I am a loser!! 

http://jsfiddle.net/46mtg48n/

Comment: Are you familiar with debugging in the browser? This should help. It is an essential tool for web development and you should definitely learn to use it if you don't already. If you want guidance, tell me what browser you're using.

Comment: Problem is missed quotes on value - $eraser.prop("value", "AHAHA");

Comment: Tell me what I have to do please

Comment: Line 12 of your fiddle. Put quotes around value, to make "value".

Answer (score 0):

I guess your JS code is being included at the top of your page? The JQuery Ready function is to let you know when the DOM is ready. If the JavaScript is all at the bottom of the page then it'll be the same thing so your code will work.

Alternatively you just have not assigned $eraser etc to anything when you've executed your code.

Comment: But $(".eraser").prop('value', sendtext5);  is not working either.

Comment: And other jQuery statements right below that statement works well

Comment: If it works in JQuery Ready and not outside of it then it means that that dom element is not there yet. Others might be, but this one isnt. If you add more context then we can guide further e.g. a JS Fiddle.

Comment: Well, and now, it does not work inside ready( ) either.   I am a loser!

http://jsfiddle.net/46mtg48n/

Comment: Nothing so dramatic.. http://jsfiddle.net/46mtg48n/1/ You were using value instead of 'value'.